# Insert a block comment title in Kile

Tags: kile, sourcecode, code, comments

I would like to know whether it is possible in Kile to define a script to insert a centered commented block.

I often mark different parts of my code with those kind of titles:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%       OLD MODEL           %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

So that it's very apparent and easy to spot *in the code itself*.

Do you know if there is any way to program Kile to get a prompt, and Kile automagically creates such a stamp, with the text automatically centered?

It can definitely be approximated by a User Tag, but this would not create a box type of things, and cannot center the words.

Thank you!